# How to add numbers inside of a program that reads data?

Tags: python

I have another program which is meant to get information and then write it into a separate text doc. For this program, I want to take the data on the text doc and format it into an output. I have managed to get the formatting correct as well as the loop to read the information correctly but am struggling to get three more variables: 1) Find the total amount due between all employees added together. 2) Find the total amount of hours all the employees worked added. 3) Find the average hours worked per week. I cannot figure out how to get these variables as the information from the text doc must be in string format (to my knowledge), and i need them to be in float to do the calculations.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
def main():

    employeeCount = 0

    infile = open("BillingTEST.txt","r")

    print("Employee Name\t\t" +
          "Rate\t" +
          "Week 1\t" +
          "Week 2\t" +
          "Week 3\t" +
          "Week 4\t" +
          "Hours\t" + "Total")

    name = readAsString(infile)

    while name != "":

        employeeCount += 1

        rate = readAsFloat(infile)
        week1 = readAsFloat(infile)
        week2 = readAsFloat(infile)
        week3 = readAsFloat(infile)
        week4 = readAsFloat(infile)

        empHours = week1+week2+week3+week4
        empMoney = empHours * rate
        


              


        print(name + "\t\t\t$" +
              str(rate)+ "\t" +
              str(week1)+"\t" +
              str(week2)+"\t" +
              str(week3)+"\t" +
              str(week4)+"\t" +
              str(empHours)+"\t" +
              str(empMoney))

        name = readAsString(infile)

    print("\nTotal Billable Due:\t"+
        "\nTotal Billable Hours:"+
        "\nAverage Billable Hours:\t"+
        "\nEmployee Count: ",employeeCount)




def readAsString(file):
    return file.readline().rstrip("\n")

def readAsFloat(file):
    return float(file.readline().rstrip("n"))

    
main()
```

Comment: Not sure did I get it, you have already a function that converts line to float, what's wrong with it?

Comment: What does the original text document look like?